# InAppBrowser sends a non-www request

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ssl-certificate, inappbrowser

I'm having a problem when I try to call my website.
I'm calling it using the link "https://www.mywebsite.com" but the in-app browser (i don't know why) is sending the request in this way: "https://mywebsite.com" and since the website I'm trying to reach does not have an SSL certificate valid for both links (it is only set for the www version of the link), it returns me the error "`ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`".

Does anyone know how do I force the in-app browser to send the response in the way that I want?
The problem is both for Android and iOS.

Thanks in advance to anyone that will try to help :D

Comment: You should inspect your html (including related resources like css and JavaScript). I‘d suspect that there‘s a link somewhere that doesn‘t have the www on it.

Comment: the problem is shown when I try to open IAB, and the link includes the www...